# Deny requests to a port ufw

Tags: http, elasticsearch, ufw

I want to deny all requests from out of my server (not localhost) to port `9200` (elasticsearch). Using `UFW` I add these rules:

```
sudo now allow 80
sudo ufw deny in 9200
```

and then restart the `UFW` but now when I check 'my_server_ip_adress:9200' I get this:

```
{
  "name": "...",
  "cluster_name": "...",
  "cluster_uuid": "YxzNYHmnTqqgXYOqOtJTCQ",
  "version": {
    "number": "5.5.2",
    "build_hash": "b2f0c09",
    "build_date": "2017-08-14T12:33:14.154Z",
    "build_snapshot": false,
    "lucene_version": "6.6.0"
  },
  "tagline": "You Know, for Search"
}
```

how can I close all access from out to this port?

Comment: I don't know why your `ufw deny` command is not working (and you should get it working still), but you can (and should) also update `network.host` in your elasticsearch.yml file (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/modules-network.html#common-network-settings)

Comment: @dshockley I am new to elasticsearch. Can you tell me it in details?

Comment: Is it possible you have an allow all before your deny? Order matters (https://serverfault.com/questions/713674/does-order-of-ufw-rules-matter) -- also probably you should provide output from `ufw status verbose`, and besides this, this is probably a question for serverfault not stackoverflow

Comment: I think you're using Ubuntu? If so your elasticsearch.yml is probably in `/etc/elasticsearch/` -- however if you haven't already updated it, I'm confused why this is happening at all, I think the default behavior should be to only allow connections from localhost. Which version of elasticsearch?

Comment: Ah sorry I see it's 5.5. And you didn't update the elasticsearch.yml already?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to deny request OUT of your server you have to use "deny out"

```
sudo ufw insert 1 deny out 9200
```

you can list your rules with:

```
sudo ufw status
```